# What's the best way to handle a list view whose cursor gets frequent reads and writes?

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I am building an Inventory application. The items are shown in a grid view and each cell of the grid view also has a TextView in the upper right corner that displays the available quantity of the item.  The user can single click on the gridview cell to increase the quantity or long click to decrease it.

I am currently using a class derived from SimpleCursorAdapter to display the data, but I am not sure about how to update the quantity in the DB. I am afraid that if I write directly to the DB and then create a new cursor and change cursor that the application might become bogged down if the user clicks repeatedly (say to add 10 items)

I have considered copying the data from the query cursor to an array in the Activity and then using an ArrayAdapter but this seems kludgy.

I have also thought about creating an array in my SimpleCursorAdapter which would cache items that have been modified and then save those items when pausing...

Is there a better way? A more Android way?

I guess this comes down to: what is the best way to make rapid changes in the DB and UI?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Cursors in this regard, but I would create a custom `ArrayAdapter` based on a model object rather than a Cursor.  That's just a personal preference, but by doing this I don't have to make any assumptions about the Cursor implementation or know it inside and out.

Let's say you're displaying a collection of type `Item` in your grid.  I would create a class called `ItemsList` that derives from `ArrayList<Item>` and my adapter would derive from `ArrayAdapter<Item>`.  The reason you create a wrapper around the `ArrayList` is that you can allow the user to interact with it freely and mark it as "dirty" and allow it to update the database asynchronously.  This way, you just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter and you don't have to think about the overhead of updating the db...you've separated interacting with the collection being displayed and the process of updating the persistent storage.

Btw...this video is a must when working with ListViews and Adapters if you haven't already seen it:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: I was actually in the audience :)  (yes, really)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular listView  and a regular Adapter with a list (arraylist) of items in it. Every time user clicks or long clicks you can edit the list in your adapter and notifyDataChanged() which will reflect the list changes on your listView. If you want to keep your list after user quits your application you can use either database(for bigger amount of data) or preferences (for smaller data amount).